# IOS/Objective-C: Flurry 8.5 crashing intermittently

Tags: ios, objective-c, flurry

MY IOS app in Objective-C is using Flurry 8.5 for analytics.  It works reasonably well but occasionally causes crashes.  From what I can tell, the crashes occur during certain conditions of Internet access.  For example, below, it seems to have occurred when initially it did not detect reachability and then reachability status changed so it tried to send a message over the Internet.  Would greatly appreciate it if anyone could suggest steps to prevent this:

Here is the log of the most recent crash:

```
2018-07-18 10:21:14.150 idaru[16918:7127063] FlurrySession: Initial timestamp[2018-06-13 12:17:49 +0000] from secure source
2018-07-18 10:21:14.156 idaru[16918:7127063] FlurryDataSender: posting session via flurryhttpasynctask!
2018-07-18 10:21:14.168 idaru[16918:7127063] -[FlurryBackgroundTaskTracker startBackgroundTaskTrackingIfNeeded]: start background task
2018-07-18 10:21:14.214 idaru[16918:7127063] FlurrySession: Initial timestamp[2018-06-13 12:17:49 +0000] from secure source
2018-07-18 10:21:14.228 idaru[16918:7127063] FlurryDataSender: posting session via flurryhttpasynctask!
2018-07-18 10:21:14.229 idaru[16918:7127063] FlurrySession: Scheduled send 2 session(s).
2018-07-18 10:21:14.239 idaru[16918:7127426] +[FlurryGlobalVariableStorage getPersistentFilePath:]: /Users/M/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/36910EEA-C1C8-46FC-8624-61B769620478/data/Containers/Data/Application/6362CFA7-5DD5-4429-958F-BB09A822C0A7/Library/Application Support/FlurryFiles/.flurryPropertiesData1639646914_227.archive
2018-07-18 10:21:14.239 idaru[16918:7127043] +[FlurryGlobalVariableStorage getPersistentFilePath:]: /Users/M/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/36910EEA-C1C8-46FC-8624-61B769620478/data/Containers/Data/Application/6362CFA7-5DD5-4429-958F-BB09A822C0A7/Library/Application Support/FlurryFiles/.flurryPersistentUrlsData1639646914_227.archive
2018-07-18 10:21:14.239 idaru[16918:7127431] +[FlurryGlobalVariableStorage getPersistentFilePath:]: /Users/M/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/36910EEA-C1C8-46FC-8624-61B769620478/data/Containers/Data/Application/6362CFA7-5DD5-4429-958F-BB09A822C0A7/Library/Application Support/FlurryFiles/.flurryCkData1639646914_227.archive
2018-07-18 10:21:14.242 idaru[16918:7127433] +[FlurryGlobalVariableStorage getPersistentFilePath:]: /Users/M/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/36910EEA-C1C8-46FC-8624-61B769620478/data/Containers/Data/Application/6362CFA7-5DD5-4429-958F-BB09A822C0A7/Library/Application Support/FlurryFiles/.flurryPersistenPulseUrlsData1639646914_227.archive
2018-07-18 10:21:14.242 idaru[16918:7127427] +[FlurryGlobalVariableStorage getPersistentFilePath:]: /Users/M/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/36910EEA-C1C8-46FC-8624-61B769620478/data/Containers/Data/Application/6362CFA7-5DD5-4429-958F-BB09A822C0A7/Library/Application Support/FlurryFiles/.flurryPersistenPulsePrepUrlsData1639646914_227.archive
2018-07-18 10:21:14.247 idaru[16918:7127063] FlurrySession: Resume session with resumeTime[2018-07-18 08:21:14 +0000]
2018-07-18 10:21:14.249 idaru[16918:7127063] FlurryDataSenderBase: networkStatusChanged to  reachable
2018-07-18 10:21:14.251 idaru[16918:7127063] Flurry: application is in background, skipping sending data.
2018-07-18 10:21:14.252 idaru[16918:7127063] FlurryDataSenderBase: networkStatusChanged to  reachable
2018-07-18 10:21:14.253 idaru[16918:7127063] Flurry: application is in background, skipping sending data.
2018-07-18 10:21:14.253 idaru[16918:7127063] Native Debug Log: ad_fetch = 0, ad_requests = 0, ads_returned = 0, ad_ready = 0, Impression fired = 0
2018-07-18 10:21:14.258 idaru[16918:7127063] FlurrySession: Sending sessions to server, include current YES
2018-07-18 10:21:14.269 idaru[16918:7127063] FlurrySession: Initial timestamp[2018-06-13 12:17:49 +0000] from secure source
2018-07-18 10:21:14.276 idaru[16918:7127063] FlurryDataSender: posting session via flurryhttpasynctask!
2018-07-18 10:21:14.278 idaru[16918:7127063] FlurrySession: Scheduled send 1 session(s).
(lldb)
```

This is what typing bt in console gives (back trace)

**EDIT**

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x00000001146f0d42 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
    frame #1: 0x00000001147fe457 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 90
  * frame #2: 0x000000010e14469b libclang_rt.tsan_iossim_dynamic.dylib`wrap_pthread_kill + 315
    frame #3: 0x000000011448288f libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 127
    frame #4: 0x000000010e14344c libclang_rt.tsan_iossim_dynamic.dylib`wrap_abort + 108
    frame #5: 0x000000010dc32261 idaru`uncaught_exception_handler + 27
    frame #6: 0x000000011237693f CoreFoundation`__handleUncaughtException + 751
    frame #7: 0x000000011186f3bb libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 94
    frame #8: 0x0000000114729f29 libc++abi.dylib`std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
    frame #9: 0x0000000114729fa3 libc++abi.dylib`std::terminate() + 51
    frame #10: 0x000000011186f343 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_terminate + 9
    frame #11: 0x000000011438e070 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 28
    frame #12: 0x00000001143710f8 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke + 579
    frame #13: 0x000000011438e05c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 8
    frame #14: 0x000000011436f40b libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 411
    frame #15: 0x00000001122d2909 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    frame #16: 0x0000000112298ae4 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2164
    frame #17: 0x0000000112298016 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406
    frame #18: 0x00000001158a8a24 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 62
    frame #19: 0x00000001128eb0d4 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 159
    frame #20: 0x000000010d930754 idaru`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007fff52642570) at main.m:15
    frame #21: 0x00000001143da65d libdyld.dylib`start + 1
(lldb)
```

Comment: Try to install latest pod version pod 'Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurrySDK'

Comment: I am not using cocoapods so running the standalone version.Reluctant to use cocoapods due to additional dependency.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by stack trace.  Here is one of the threads:  libsystem_kernel.dylib`__semwait_signal:
    0x10f6f6f3c <+0>:  movl   $0x200014e, %eax          ; imm = 0x200014E 
    0x10f6f6f41 <+5>:  movq   %rcx, %r10
    0x10f6f6f44 <+8>:  syscall 
->  0x10f6f6f46 <+10>: jae    0x10f6f6f50               ; <+20>
    0x10f6f6f48 <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x10f6f6f4b <+15>: jmp    0x10f6efcd4               ; cerror
    0x10f6f6f50 <+20>: retq   
    0x10f6f6f51 <+21>: nop    
    0x10f6f6f52 <+22>: nop    
    0x10f6f6f53 <+23>: nop

Comment: Added bt output

Comment: After crash, Main thread, 20 is highlighted.  It shows in debugger pane: argc int 1
argv char ** 0x7fff570ae568 0x00007fff570ae568
*argv char * "/Users/M/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/36910EEA-C1C8-46FC-8624-61B769620478/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F1A588DF-E8B4-49AC-83EF-1ECEBFBE5752/idaru.app/idaru" 0x00007fff570ae808

Comment: Thank you. Did you follow the instructions for manual integration here: https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/integrateflurry/ios-manual/ and add the required Frameworks?

Comment: Yes.  I am not experiencing this problem all the time or on an iphone se.  I am experiencing it on the simulator for 7Plus